# Set background color of page with style

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've defined the following explicit style in `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style TargetType="ContentPage" x:Key="PageStyle">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#ff0000" />
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The page, which I want to show, is embedded into a `NavigationPage` and has derived from `ContentPage`. It has the following implicit style, whereas here `ContentPage` instead of my derived type is used (in real I use the derived type, but I tried it without and I had the same effect):

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style TargetType="ContentPage" BasedOn="{StaticResource PageStyle}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

But the background of the page doesn't change. It always shows the default background color of the platform. If I use a style for a `Button`, the style is applied. I tried it with `NavigationPage`, `ContentPage`, `Page`, `VisualElement`, but the background is always the default background.

If I explicitly set the color with

```
<ContentPage.BackgroundColor>
    <Color>Red</Color>
</ContentPage.BackgroundColor>
```

or

```
this.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
```

the color is applied.

Comment: Obligatory Question: The background isn't set in the designer?

Comment: Currently there is no designer available. You can only use XML or C#.

Comment: Rephrase: Is the BackgroundColor Dependency Property Set Explicitly anywhere in your XML or C#?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with *BackgroundColor Dependency Property*? I have defined a style on application level (with the background setter), which I want to use on a page. In this case the background color is set in XML.

Comment: Could help [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/34798/how-to-add-global-background-color-style) topic.

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy: I saw that before, but the informations I found didn't helped me yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the style to your ContentPage like this:

```
<ContentPage (...) Style="{StaticResource PageStyle}">
```

Comment: Do you know why converting from an explicit to an implicit style doesn't work for pages?

Comment: Sadly I have no idea. If you don't want to set the background on each ContentPage, then create a new class inheriting from ContentPage, set the background in it's xaml/constructor using style from App.xaml and then use this class instead of ContentPage. That's a bit naive, but if the simplest solution doesn't work, so... Here's a page with this behavior, but probably the last post is yours: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=27659

Answer (score 20):

You can assign it globally, you have to set `ApplyToDerivedTypes` to true. Here is an example:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentPage" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#4A4A4A" />
</Style>
```

Now **all** classes that inherit ContentPage will have this background color.

Comment: Straight forward answer... Thanks.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for that behavior is that `SomePage` (in my case) is subclassed from `ContentPage`. I found that in the [documentation for implicit styles](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/implicit/):

> However, the Style is not applied to the CustomEntry instance, which is a subclassed Entry

So implicit styles doesn't work with subclasses. But every page is a subclass from `ContentPage`. You can only use the solution from [Michał Ż](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39250823/426227).